# How to display non-empty array only (VBnet)

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have an array as follows:

```
If iAdvanceMonthNum = 1 Then
   iAdvanceMonthName(1) = "January"
ElseIf iAdvanceMonthNum = 2 Then
   iAdvanceMonthName(2) = "February"
ElseIf iAdvanceMonthNum = 3 Then
   iAdvanceMonthName(3) = "March"
ElseIf iAdvanceMonthNum = 4 Then
   iAdvanceMonthName(4) = "April"
ElseIf iAdvanceMonthNum = 5 Then
   iAdvanceMonthName(5) = "May"
ElseIf iAdvanceMonthNum = 6 Then
   iAdvanceMonthName(6) = "June"
ElseIf iAdvanceMonthNum = 7 Then
   iAdvanceMonthName(7) = "July"
ElseIf iAdvanceMonthNum = 8 Then
   iAdvanceMonthName(8) = "August"
ElseIf iAdvanceMonthNum = 9 Then
   iAdvanceMonthName(9) = "September"
ElseIf iAdvanceMonthNum = 10 Then
   iAdvanceMonthName(10) = "October"
ElseIf iAdvanceMonthNum = 11 Then
   iAdvanceMonthName(11) = "November"
ElseIf iAdvanceMonthNum = 12 Then
   iAdvanceMonthName(12) = "December"
End If
```

Let say the array will be:
iAdvanceMonth(9) = "September" and
iAdvanceMonth(10) = "October"

while the other array will be null. What I want to achieve is that I want to display "September" and "October".

The code to display the string that I have done so far:

```
Dim display As String = String.Empty
For i As Integer = 1 To iAdvanceMonthName.Length - 1
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(iAdvanceMonthName(i)) Then
        display = iAdvanceMonthName(i)
    End If
Next
```

However, the output will only be "October" as the code will take the latest array. Can I get some hints or tips on how to solve this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
    Dim display As String = String.Empty
    For i As Integer = 1 To iAdvanceMonthName.Length - 1
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(iAdvanceMonthName(i)) Then
            display = display & iAdvanceMonthName(i) & " And "
        End If
    Next
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(display) Then display = Left(display, display.Length - 5)
```

Comment: Thanks for this sir, its almost work but there is an error at Left function;

"Public Property Left As Integer' has no parameters and its return type cannot be indexed"

Comment: Okay, got it!

`Dim display As String = String.Empty
    For i As Integer = 1 To iAdvanceMonthName.Length - 1
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(iAdvanceMonthName(i)) Then
            display = display & iAdvanceMonthName(i) & " And "
        End If
    Next
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(display) Then
display = display.Substring(0, display.Length - 5)
End If`

Answer (score 0):

Check this code:

Framework 4.0+

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim months As String() = {Nothing, "August", "September", ""}
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" and ", months.Where(Function(s) Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))))


        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

**EDIT**

Framework 4.0-

```
Module Module1

        Sub Main()
            Dim months As String() = {Nothing, "August", "September", ""}
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" and ", months.Where(Function(s) Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).ToArray))


            Console.ReadLine()
        End Sub

    End Module
```

Comment: I got this error sir;

"Unable to cast object of type 'WhereArrayIterator'1[System.String]' to type 'System.String[]'"

Comment: Very strange because this is actual test code on VS 2013 on framework 4.5

Comment: In framework 4.0 there is an overload of Join `String.Join<T> Method (String, IEnumerable<T>)`. I guess that you are using a previous framework version. Check my edit.